# Spring context configuration

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsf, spring-mvc

I´m trying to configure spring + hibernate + jsf in my web application with a glassfish 4.0 server. I use Hibernate in the   persistence layer, spring for the business layer and jsf for the web layer. I have configured the hibernate and jsf layers properly. But while I´m trying to configure the spring layer, it doesn´t work.

For configuring the database, I have use MySQL Workbench, and I have connected the hibernate layer with the database properly, all the POJOS are properly created.

But now Im trying to add the spring layer, and it gives me an error in my Application context. The error displayed shows as follows:

And my Aplication file is like this:

```
Error occurred during deployment: Exception while loading the app :java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 13 in XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/salon_bazter.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 13; columnNumber: 90; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: El comodín coincidente es estricto, pero no se ha encontrado ninguna declaración para el elemento 'jee:jndi-lookup'.. Please see server.log for more details.
```

And the log shows this exception:

```
ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException:org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 13 in XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/salon_bazter.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 13; columnNumber: 90; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: El comodín coincidente es estricto, pero no se ha encontrado ninguna declaración para el elemento 'jee:jndi-lookup'.
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5920)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:691)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:1041)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:1024)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:747)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2278)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1924)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:139)
at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:122)
at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:291)
at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:352)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:497)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:527)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:523)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:356).......
```

My Aplication context shows as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx"

   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd 
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-txd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">
<!--Para obtener el pool de conexiones vía jndi name-->
<jee:jndi-lookup id="salonBazterDataSource" jndi-name="jdbc/centro_belleza_bazter" />

<!--Para declarar una factoría de Sesiones de hibernate-->
<bean id="miSessionFact"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="salonBazterDataSource" />
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>model.Cliente</value>
            <value>model.Noticias</value>
            <value>model.Tratamiento</value>
            <value>model.Historico</value>
            <value>model.VentaTratamiento</value>
            <value>model.Agenda</value>
            <value>model.Proveedor</value>
            <value>model.Trabajador</value>
            <value>model.Producto</value>               

        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect" >org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql" >true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql" >true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<!--Para declarar un Gestor transaccional de Hibernate-->
<bean id="transactionManager"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="miSessionFact" />
</bean>

<!--Para definir que el Contexto transaccional será administrado por contenedor-->
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
<!--Para definir un bean de tipo noticiasService-->
 <bean id="noticiasService" class="negocio.clientes.NoticiasServiceImpl" >
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="miSessionFact" />
</bean>
```

The problem seems to be in my jndi declaration. The glassfish-resources where the jdbc is created, looks as follows:

```
<resources>

<jdbc-resource enabled="true" jndi-name="jdbc/centro_belleza_bazter" object-type="user" pool-name="connectionPoolBazter">
  <description/>
 </jdbc-resource>

<jdbc-connection-pool allow-non-component-callers="false" associate-with-thread="false" connection-creation-retry-attempts="0" connection-creation-retry-interval-in-seconds="10" connection-leak-reclaim="false" connection-leak-timeout-in-seconds="0" connection-validation-method="auto-commit" datasource-classname="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource" fail-all-connections="false" idle-timeout-in-seconds="300" is-connection-validation-required="false" is-isolation-level-guaranteed="true" lazy-connection-association="false" lazy-connection-enlistment="false" match-connections="false" max-connection-usage-count="0" max-pool-size="32" max-wait-time-in-millis="60000" name="connectionPoolBazter" non-transactional-connections="false" ping="false" pool-resize-quantity="2" pooling="true" res-type="javax.sql.DataSource" statement-cache-size="0" statement-leak-reclaim="false" statement-leak-timeout-in-seconds="0" statement-timeout-in-seconds="-1" steady-pool-size="8" validate-atmost-once-period-in-seconds="0" wrap-jdbc-objects="true">
<property name="URL" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/centro_belleza_bazter?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull"/>
<property name="User" value="root"/>
<property name="Password" value="root"/>
 </jdbc-connection-pool>
 </resources>
```

Could anybody help me??? Does anybody had the same problem???

Thanks in advance!!!!

Comment: Did you read the exception? `Line 13 in XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/salon_bazter.xml] is invalid;`

Comment: I read it, it seems to be with a problem with the jndi, but i have created my conecction pool properly in glassfish, and i have called it like it shows "jdbc/centro_belleza_bazter". I know that the problems seems to be in that line, but i don´t know why, it could be a problem with the libraries imported???

Answer (score 2):

Your xml file contains multiple errors

1. Your `jee` and `tx` namespace mappings are wrong
2. Your schema locations are wrong

### namespace mappings

```
xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-2.5.xsd"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd"
```

This is intended to create a shorthand to a particular namespace not a schema location. So you have to use the namespace uri.

```
xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx"
```

These should map also to locations in either the class path or explicitly be mapped in your schema locations. Those are also wrong

### Schema location

```
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-2.5.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-2.5.xsd/spring-spring-jee-2.5.xsd-3.1.1.RELEASE.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd/spring-spring-tx-2.5.xsd-3.1.1.RELEASE.xsd">
```

The syntax for schema locations is `[namespace] [schema location]`, just as the one above the 2 for the `beans` namespace.

```
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-txd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
```

When using spring with namespace it is also advised to use the version less schema this will always point to the most recent version of spring in your class path.

Comment: I have tried, as you said, and it doesn´t work, what spring library are you using???? I have used Spring Framework 3.1.1.RELEASE

Comment: The namespace and the schema location, have been created by the system, i have not touch them while creating my Application context

Comment: Fact remains they are plain wrong… No matter if you created them yourself or your system…

Comment: Now I´m trying with: <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"

Comment: xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd  
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-txd
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

Comment: Have you actually read/applied my answer? Judging from what you are posting here (the namespace mapping) you haven't. Fix your mappings there must be an http:// in front of them…

Comment: Sorry, it was my fault. I try it again as you said, but still doesn´t work. I try to comment all my code in the application context with the purpose of cleaning it, and if I only put the namespace and the schema location, the application works. The problem is when I put <jee:jndi-lookup id="salonBazterDataSource" jndi-name="jdbc/centro_belleza_bazter" /> this line. It seems like it is not catching my jndi. Do you know why it could be???

Comment: Post your current configuraiton (not as a comment, but to your post). It doesn't work if it cannot find the declaration. Make sure you have allt he jars in your classpath and post the new stacktrace.

Comment: Thanks for the support, I have edited my post with the new configuration. Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Change your:

```
xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-2.5.xsd"
```

to:

```
xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
```

and in your schemalocation change the part with the:

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-2.5.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-2.5.xsd/spring-spring-jee-2.5.xsd-3.1.1.RELEASE.xsd
```

to:

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee
http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-2.5.xsd
```

Note: if this was the problem then you might have a similar one with the tx namespace.

Comment: I have tryed to change it, but it doesn´t work, it could be a problem with the spring library??? I have used Spring Framework 3.1.1.RELEASE. And the schema location has been created by the system when i created the application context